# Where Sys.Net.WebServiceProxy is defined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wcf

Trying to use JavaScript to call WCF web service using its generated proxy class. Proxy class contains line:

```
IDemoWCFService.registerClass('IDemoWCFService',Sys.Net.WebServiceProxy);
```

And Chrome browser is angry about that with error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined
```

I suppose I need to include some library. Which one and where? If not how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, if you add your script reference with

```
<asp:scriptmanager ....
```

references to other dependant libraries are added automatically.

Most probably, however, you reference your script directly (`...svc/js`). If this is so, you need to reference auxiliary libraries:

- MicrosoftAjax.js - this one contains the definition of `Sys.Net.WebServiceProxy`
- MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js - this one is needed in a webforms app

Both can be included from their CDN, http://www.asp.net/ajax/cdn, just look for *ASP.NET Web Forms and Ajax Releases on the CDN* and include correct version (for .net 3, 4 or 4.5.2)

For example, go to:

http://www.asp.net/ajax/cdn/cdnajax452

and find

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5.2/1/MicrosoftAjax.js

listed as one of available libraries. There are other libraries available, if needed.